# Disable split screen in react native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

does anybody know how to disable split screen in a React native expo app?. I have found in the docs this solution but only for ios. Thanks a lot in advance

```
Open your app.json and add the following inside of the "expo" field:
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "ios": {
      ...
      "requireFullScreen": true,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super quick response but in my expo project I can't find that AndroidManifest.xml file. I will try to update it with this solution.... https://chafikgharbi.com/expo-android-manifest/

Comment: It's under the android folder of your project. If it works, please mark it as answer.

Comment: As far as I know AndroidManifest.xml can't be modify directly in expo projects, I should eject to have access to that file. However I will try this https://chafikgharbi.com/expo-android-manifest/ and if it works I will be glad to verify your answer