# React Native screen orientation lock doesn't work with expo

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a react native project with `expo v48` and I need to lock the screen in orientation landscape. I used their library `expo-screen-orientation` but it has a little problem. As you can read the warning at the top of the page of [their documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=performancemax&gclid=CjwKCAjwhJukBhBPEiwAniIcNQ91sFsfqLpgCP8ULFEwQ1zsakrro-MjcXH6FCby_R1CzMgZcPDXxxoCA1cQAvD_BwE), it doesn't work with iOS since Apple added support for screen split. It also says that if I need to make it work there is needed to disable the support for that feature (I am talking about the *split screen*). I've found [something on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546796/disable-split-screen-in-react-native-expo-app) but it is for android and it would't work anyway.

I configured the app.json just like the doc says:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "requireFullScreen": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-screen-orientation",
        {
          "initialOrientation": "DEFAULT"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Do you know how to make this library work? Or is there a way to disable the split screen feature on ios from an `expo v48` project?

p.s. On Android everything works fine.

Comment: have you solved this issue? i`m facing the same problem!

Comment: @4aLifeTime I din't. It should be solved in v49 of expo. Take a look here https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-49-c6d398cdf740! they talking about it